# Sharing multiple photos with ShareMediaTask

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, task

Is it possible to use `ShareMediaTask` to share multiple photos at once?

In Windows Phone 8 built-in photo viewer, user can select multiple photos then share these photos.

My code for sharing a single photo

```
private void sharePhoto(BitmapImage bitmap)
    {
        try
        {
            WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(bitmap);
            int width = (int)wb.PixelWidth;
            int height = (int)wb.PixelHeight;

            using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream(width * height * 4))
            {
                wb.SaveJpeg(stream, width, height, 0, 100);
                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                var lib = new MediaLibrary();
                var picture = lib.SavePicture(string.Format(selectedPhoto.FileName), stream);

                var shareMediaTask = new ShareMediaTask();
                shareMediaTask.FilePath = picture.GetPath();                    
                shareMediaTask.Show();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error at sharePhoto: " + e.Message);                
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207027%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) says:

> The share picker allows your app to share **a media item** with one of the
>   media-sharing apps that are installed on the phone.

Unfortunatly there are no other tasks available either to allow the sharing of several media items, the only option I can see is if there is any third-party app which has a [custom URI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) which can be launched to share multiple items.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that with the `ShareMediaTask`. System apps like the photo viewer can use APIs that are not available to developers, so they can basically do just anything.